# Mutate new column and paste value from existing columns depending on the value of another column

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is a simplified version of my dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(
  category = c(1,2,3,4,5), 
  yend = c(13, 15, 4, 18, 6), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to mutate `y` with the same values of yend but one category below. I guess there are multiple ways of doing this, and my desired output would be this:

```
  category yend  y
1        1   13  0
2        2   15 13
3        3    4 15
4        4   18  4
5        5    6 18
```

What I have been trying is this:

```
df_test <- df |>
  mutate(y=case_when(
    category=='1' ~ '0'),
    category=='2' ~ [[[TAKE VALUE FROM yend, category=1]]]
```

But I have no idea how to write the last line. I would do the same for categories 2 to 5. I suppose there are multiple ways to solve this and I may be complicating it too much.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `mutate(y = lag(yend, 1, default = 0))`?

Comment: Is it always the case that each category appears in one row and they're in order? If a category can appear in multiple rows, do those each have the same `y` values?

Comment: The category is only in one row, but they repeat a lot of times because I have 5 categories per country. So each time they have different values. I am grouping them already beforehand with `group_by`. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df |> mutate(y = lag(yend,1,default=0))
```

gives

```
  category yend  y
1        1   13  0
2        2   15 13
3        3    4 15
4        4   18  4
5        5    6 18
```

Comment: Amazing at how simple it is! Thanks. Out of curiosity, do you know if there would be a way to solve this using `case_when`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `dplyr::lag`:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

df |>
  mutate(y = lag(yend, default = 0))
#>   category yend  y
#> 1        1   13  0
#> 2        2   15 13
#> 3        3    4 15
#> 4        4   18  4
#> 5        5    6 18
```